# Does being Yotzei a Bracha count for 100?

Tags: number, blessing, motzi-yedei-chovato

There are many brachos where by listening to the bracha one can be yotzei his obligation for that bracha. If someone does do so, does that bracha count towards the quota of 100 brochos a day?

Answer (score 9):

Shulchan Aruch ([Orach Chaim 284:3](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49625&st=&pgnum=124)) says that "one must pay attention to the berachos recited by those called to the Torah and by the maftir, and answer Amen to them, which will count towards the total of 100 berachos that one is short of on Shabbos."

That said, Mishnah Berurah ([46:14](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14170&st=&pgnum=147)) says that this is only ע"פ הדחק, where you don't have another way to do so. His source for this, Magen Avraham (46:8) citing Maharam Mitrani, is even more explicit: this works, he says, only if you don't have fruits or other ways to complete the 100 berachos yourself.

Comment: IINM Rav Shlomo Zalman Aurbach rules in Halichot Shlomo that this can be done even lechatchila.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, being yotzeh a bracha is no different than saying the bracha yourself... otherwise you would still have to say it!

Comment: How would you understand Rambam Brachot 1:11?

Comment: The normal way.  What's the question?

Comment: He seems to distinguish between Yatza and Harei Hu Kemevarech, ie being yotzei is not like saying it yourself but if you said Amen then it is.

Comment: When I wrote "yotzeh" I meant, "You fulfilled your obligation to say the beracha", whether that is done by listening alone or saying Amen, is not something I knew there were arguments about. I had always assumed you only fulfill your obligation by saying Amen, after listening, and that you need to do both.  If there are opinions that state otherwise, then that's for a different question.  IOW, I don't think Ramabam is really making a distinction, but he might be responding to other sources that do.

Comment: I'm not aware of anyone who holds you need to say amen to be yotzeh when the mevarech is being yotzeh as well. See my answer here http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/19126/759 The Rambam is very clear on the matter that Amen is _not_ necessary to be yotzeh.