# Men making Kiddush (Shabbos day) for women after eating at shul

Tags: halacha, shabbat, halacha-theory, women, kiddush

Women and men are both equally chayiv in kiddush, at least on shabbos. Additionally there is a commonly known rule that a non obligated person (or obligated on a lower level) cannot fulfill a mitzvah on behalf of somone who is obligated. I’ve heard it said in the name of Rabbi Akiva Eger that men can make kiddush for women even after davening (and becoming only rabbinicly obligated) because in fact they're still obligated מדאורייתא because they intended not to "give up" their obligation.

But what about on Shabbos day, where they actually make kiddush in shul then go home? Then they aren't obligated anymore because they DID intend to get rid of their obligation and the women are still obligated rabbinically (it's day so it's not מדאורייתא).

So why the common Minhag for men is to eat kiddush at shul and still make kiddush for their family's at home?

Comment: אע"פ שיצא מוציא, but then you're getting into the machlokes if there is arvus for women. See MB and Shaar HaTziyun 271

Comment: @rovev What's your first quote saying? And what is 'arvus'?

Comment: Sorry I don't have time to write a formal answer. Here's some sources: https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.271.2?with=Mishnah%20Berurah&lang=bi

Comment: Dealing with the part of the question about controlling/suppressing fulfillment of the _mitzva_ during the day: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/60347/3 @robev

Comment: @robev RAE, who Orion seems to be going with, says there is arvus for women.

Comment: According to those authorities that he is already exempted of the obligation of *Kiddusha rabba* of the day, perhaps his (rabbinic) obligation of *bracha rishona* (*hagafen*) is considered at the same (rabbinic) level as her remaining (rabbinic) obligation of *kiddusha rabba*.   In addition, I believe many authorities say he still needs *kiddush bmakom seuda* anyway, and that the cake in shul did not count - so both he and she are obligated at the same rabbinic level of *kiddusha rabba* regardless.

Comment: @loewian                                                               A) Isn't cake considered a seudah? It's Mizonot. Plus many kiddeishim also have meat and other things.                                       B) I don't think different obligations will help even if they are both the same level. If being obligated in a action because of one mitzvah would allow you to do a mitzvah on behalf of somone else with that action, then wouldn't women be able to do any mitzvah for a man by swearing to that mitzvah? She'd be obligated on the same level also

Comment: A) I'm certainly not suggesting it's unanimous.  But I would also think that if they were being *kovea seuda* on the cake, they should be washing and bentshing as well. B) I hear your point.  But perhaps one could argue that we're more lenient with drabanans.

Comment: @orion some think you need bread for a seudah

Answer (score 3):

I think you are confusing the different concepts. The discussion about a man being *motze* his wife on Friday night is a very different conversation to that of Shabbos day.

**Friday night:** This discussion revolves around the dispute whether *arvus* - the concept that one can exempt his fellow's obligation even after he has discharged his own -  exists from a man to a woman (See *Dagul Mervava* and *R' Akiva Eiger* on Shulchan Aruch 271). A secondary discussion is whether a man is actually *yotzei* his own obligation during Friday night prayers, when he (a) doesn't mention Yetzias Mitzrayim, and (b) has no intention of being (or specific intention not to be) *yotzei*.

**Shabbos day**: This discussion is very different, because there is no need to factor *arvus*. Unlike Friday night, there is no *bracha* of Kiddush to make on his wife's behalf; the whole Kiddush is simply the regular *borei pri hagafen*. Any person who drinks grape juice or wine is obligated in this blessing too; as long as the husband drinks from the *kos*, this blessing is for himself as much as it is for her. Therefore, even without activating the mechanism of *arvus*, he can discharge his wife in her obligation using the concept of *shomea k'oineh*, just like he can be *motzi* her in *hamotzi*. *Arvus* is only necessary when the person making the blessing cannot make it for himself, but would like to make it on behalf of his friend.

Answer (score -1):

R' Akiva Eiger in fact says (in Orach Chaim 271) that men can say kiddush after davening despite already having fulfilled their obligation, as in the first place they both have the same obligation. Those who argue (Dagul Mervava) maintain that there is a problem even on Friday night.