Kiddush without a se'udah
If one makes kiddush and its not followed by a meal the Michaber (Siman 273:3) rules that he is not yotzie kiddush. My question is; does he mean that he is not yotzie even on a biblical level? Or that since many rishonim say kiddush on a biblical level need be only "words", its only the rabbinic level of kiddush that he is missing. [Nafka mina would be regarding discharging someone else's obligation]

Possible duplicate of https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/60347/kiddush-for-someone-else-excluding-myself “Yes, you may. See Shulchan Aruch siman 273 siff 4 'One may make kidush for others even though he is not eating with them, because for them it is kidush in the place they are eating.”

Also worth considering if his kiddush was a bracha levatala. Maybe it's just he has an obligation to do it a second time.

Kiddush bimakom seuda is rabbinic. In fact many achronim/reushonim hold youre yotza kiddush deoraisa in davening. And rabbi akiva Eiger holds you're yotza deoraisa just by saying good shabbos.
