# Women answering "amen" to a bracha over a man's mitzvah

Tags: blessing, women, amen

Can/should a woman answer "amen" to a bracha a man makes over a mitzvah specific to men? For example, tzitzis, tefillin, etc.

Comment: Why not?.......Just because she can't make the bracha herself, she would consider it a bracha levatala? What about if I hear someone make a bracha on a mitzvah I'm not obligated in...like birkas kohanim

Comment: Duplicate? https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/19125/472 (a broader question that seems to encompass this one)

Comment: I'm not seeing this situation as any different from the numerous situations where someone answers "Amen" to a bracha that doesn't apply to him or her. When someone makes a bracha before eating tree fungi, don't you answer "Amen" even though you're not eating the tree fungi?

Comment: Are you asking specifically according to the Rishonim that say the women couldn't make those blessings herself if she voluntarily did those Mitzvot? But anyway robev is right about kohanim